# Docker. The driver executable does not exist: /chromedriver.exe

Tags: java, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver

I have added chromedriver.exe to my java project. So I reference it like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
```

It runs fine in Eclipse. But when running my jar file in docker, I get the following error:
[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome
# Install chromedriver for Selenium
RUN curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.140/chromedriver_linux64.zip -o /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

WORKDIR /
ADD selenium.jar selenium.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -jar selenium.jar
```

Comment: Show dockerfile and how you copy driver exe to your image/container.

Answer (score 2):

How can a .exe file can run on linux ?

Try to remove a `.exe` extension from your SetProperty.

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
```

Windows should reslove successfully executable path as well

Comment: Good point! when using Linux docker you need to use Linux chromedriver! But if OP is running on windows he might want to change the download to .exe...